# Wamp- command line "mysqld" doesn't work

Tags: mysql, wamp

When I write the command line `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\bin>mysqld`
nothing happens. It just shows the path again `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\bin>`

and when I write this: 
`C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\bin>mysql` 
it shows an error: `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to mysql server on 'localhost' (10061)`

I tried a lot to find an answer to this, but I couldn't find anything useful. Why isn't the server working?
I installed the same program for my friend, too and it works fine for her.

Comment: You dont need to use the command line. Use the WAMPServer icon menus to start MYSQL and Apache come to that

Comment: `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to mysql server on 'localhost` thats because the MYSQL service is not started

Comment: It sounds to me like you have another `my.ini` on your system somewhere. Search for `my.ini` and/or `my.cnf` on the C: drive and if you find one that is outside the `C:/wamp` folder structure - delete it.

Comment: I looked for both of them but there isn't another `my.ini`  file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to mysql server on 'localhost' (10061)` means that the MySQL server daemon is not running and so the client `mysql` can not connect. That makes sense, because `mysqld` doesn't start.

There are plenty of reasons, often its simply a misconfiguration or port collision (3306 already used?).

The first step is to make sure that the daemon is working without a configuration file. Please try to start the daemon by using `mysqld --no-defaults`. 
`no-defaults` means that mysql will not read any option files, before starting.
If it starts up, you know that the configuration file(s) are to blame.

Then search in your `my.ini` for "wrong" or "old and deprecated" entries and fix them, to allow a normal startup. Its also helpful to enable logging.

If you are in doubt, go with one of the default configuration files: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-default-configuration-file.html

You can check the ports with a tool like [CurrPorts](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html):
http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.zip

Comment: I started the daemon and I got a warning. I checked my `my.ini`  file but I just started to learn about mysql, so I don't know much about it. I am not sure what exactly you mean by invalid/wrong entries. How can I know if the port 3306 is already used?

Comment: Which warning you got ? | It could be that during the installation of the stack the installer modifies the `my.ini` file, for instance to set the correct install path - if that goes wrong, the ini might contain a wrong valid or have a bad syntax. | If you are in doubt, go with one of the default configuration files: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-default-configuration-file.html | You can check the ports with a tool like CurrPorts: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html - http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.zip

Comment: I got this warning:
`[Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is 
deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option 
(see documentation for more details).` I also checked the ports but no other process is using the same port. After that I looked for the configuration files but I couldn't find them. I googled a bit and find this one: [link](https://code.google.com/p/fusionleaf/source/browse/app/mysql/my-medium.ini?r=e429ee93ca580175c34605358e5fcb1d33a91189). I copied it and replaced it with my `my.ini` file and tried the command line again.

Comment: Then I tried the command line again I got the same warning as above. I don't understand what this warning means. So I went to Services and found `wampmysqld` was stopped (it wasn't there before I changed the `my.ini` file.) I started it. I still get this warning but `mysql` works. Now the `wampmysqld` is running but do I have to start it in this way every time? I'll try to restart my laptop and see what happens.

Comment: Glad you solved the issue by restarting the service. The warning is because of a old and deprecated setting in your config file. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_explicit_defaults_for_timestamp

Comment: I am not sure if my problem is solved completely. Because when I write this command `mysqld` and press enter the same path appears again, just like I mentioned in the question above. But my friend said that there appears only an underscore or maybe nothing happens. | But when I type `mysql` it works fine. Is this a problem that should be fixed or can I just ignore it?

Comment: When you run `mysqld` on the CLI you should get a note saying that the server was started (the server will then run in the background) and the command returns to the CLI prompt immediately. Looks like this: http://imgur.com/7akX8Vl

Comment: Maybe it differs form one person to another? However, mysql is now working fine. Thank you very much for your help and effort.